# There is a different way to write this code? c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I am new in IT and my teacher gave us this exercise

Write a console application that asks the user to input numbers between 1-20.  A user should not be able to input numbers outside of 1 and 20.
To finish inputting numbers the user should type 0.
You should then print to the screen the amount of times a user inputted a number greater than 10.

I wrote this code and it is working good

```
        int counter = 0;
        int[] num = new int[10000];
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers between 1-20. To finish inputting numbers type 0");

        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            num[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(num[i] > 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
                break;
            }
            else if(num[i] < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
                break;
            }
            else if(num[i] == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(num[i] > 10)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You entered a number greater than ten {0} times", counter);
```

I am a very curious person and what i like most of coding is that people are going to write in differents way but in the end the result will be the same.
So i am curious to see how would you solve it, to improve my knowledge

Comment: Post it at [codereview.se].

Comment: @JohnnyMopp So far i didnt know about this website. Thanks for sharing

Comment: You don't need the array.  What happens if the user wants to enter more than 10,000 numbers?  What happens if the user types in "numbersbetween1and20stink"?